# Mathematica TravelTime doesnt work for some Coordinates

Tags: database, wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha

if you try to figure out the Travel Time between:

```
TravelTime[{GeoPosition[{40.11, -88.24}], GeoPosition[{41.84, -87.69}]}]
```

It works fine.

But, when we use the coordinates we need, Mathematica gives us following exception:

```
TravelTime[{GeoPosition[{48.137, 11.575}], GeoPosition[{53.149, 8.693}]}]
```

> TravelTime::noroute TravelTime::noroute: Cannot compute path with
>   travel method Driving between locations
>   {GeoPosition[{48.137,11.575}],GeoPosition[{53.149,8.693}]}.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what are these 2 locations ?

Comment: @magma just location in Germany I calculated with GeoPosition[FindGeoLocation[name]]

Answer (score 0):

Likely because [the second point is in water](https://www.google.com/maps/place/53%C2%B008'56.4%22N+8%C2%B041'34.8%22E/@53.1481024,8.6932414,16z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d53.149!4d8.693).

If you [tweak the lon/lat slightly](https://www.google.com/maps/place/53%C2%B008'45.6%22N+8%C2%B041'31.2%22E/@53.146012,8.6832238,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d53.146!4d8.692) it should work.  i.e.:

```
TravelTime[{GeoPosition[{48.137, 11.575}], GeoPosition[{53.146, 8.692}]}]
```